# express is not fetching react build folder

Tags: reactjs, express

I'm trying to deploy a react + express app, but locally `npm start` does not fetch the react build that is within the `client` folder.

I have already done a react build, so a **build folder does exist within the client folder.**

folder structure

[image]

full folder structure

[image]

**main.js**

```
import 'dotenv/config';
import cors from 'cors';
import express from 'express';
import logger from 'morgan';
import path from 'path';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';
import userRoute from './routes/users';
import imageRoute from './routes/images';
import passport from 'passport';
import session from 'express-session';
import './config/passport';
import knex from 'knex';
import config from './knexfile'
import KnexSessionStore from 'connect-session-knex';
const knexSession = KnexSessionStore(session);
const myKnex = knex(config.development);
const store = new knexSession({
  knex:myKnex,
  // tablename:'sessions'
})

const app = express();

app.use(cors({
  origin:process.env.ALLOW_ORIGIN,
  preflightContinue: false,
  credentials: true,
  allowedHeaders: 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Authorization',
  methods: 'GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS',
  exposedHeaders: ['Content-Length', 'X-Foo', 'X-Bar'],
}))


app.use(logger('dev'));
// For React Stuff if need be
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
// you need body parser urlencoded so passport will not give a Missing Credentials error
app.use(session({
  store: store, 
  saveUninitialized: false,
  resave:false,
  cookie: {   maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 },  // 30 days
  secret : process.env.JWT_SECRET,

}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended:false})); 
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World!');
});
app.use('/users', userRoute);
app.use('/images', imageRoute);
// app.use('/images', imageRoute);
// app.use('/comments', imageRoute);
app.use(() => (req, res, next)  =>{
  res.locals.user = req.user; // This is the important line
  // req.session.user = user
  console.log(res.locals.user);
  next();
});

app.use('/', function (req, res, next) {
  var n = req.session.views || 0
  req.session.views = ++n
  res.end(n + ' views')
  console.log(n);
})

//build mode
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build')));
// if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build')));
  //
  app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendfile(path.join(__dirname = 'client/build/index.html'));
  })
// }
//build mode
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/client/public/index.html'));
})


// module.parent prevents the 
// Node / Express: EADDRINUSE, Address already in use error when unit testing
if(!module.parent){
  app.listen(process.env.PORT, () =>
    console.log(`Example app listening on port ${process.env.PORT}!`),
  );
 }

export default app;
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "somethingapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "client-install": "npm install --prefix client",
    "test": "./node_modules/.bin/mocha --watch --require @babel/register",
    "server": "nodemon --exec babel-node main.js",
    "client": "cd ./client && npm start ",
    "start": "babel-node main.js",
    "startdev": "concurrently --kill-others  \"npm run client\" \"npm run server\" ",
    "migrate": "babel-node node_modules/.bin/knex migrate:latest",
    "rollback": "babel-node node_modules/.bin/knex migrate:rollback ",
    "seed": "babel-node node_modules/.bin/knex seed:run",
    "heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client",
    "build": "concurrently \"cd client && npm run build\" \"npm build \""
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^3.0.6",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "bookshelf": "^0.14.2",
    "bookshelf-validate": "^2.0.3",
    "chai-http": "^4.3.0",
    "cloudinary": "^1.14.0",
    "concurrently": "^4.1.0",
    "connect-multiparty": "^2.2.0",
    "connect-session-knex": "^1.4.0",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.4",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^8.0.0",
    "dump-die": "^1.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.0",
    "express-session": "^1.16.1",
    "express-validator": "^5.3.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "knex": "^0.16.5",
    "morgan": "^1.9.1",
    "multer": "^1.4.1",
    "multiparty": "^4.2.1",
    "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "passport-github": "^1.1.0",
    "passport-google-oauth": "^2.0.0",
    "passport-google-oauth20": "^2.0.0",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "pg": "^7.11.0",
    "validator": "^11.0.0",
    "var_dump": "^1.0.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.5",
    "@babel/node": "^7.4.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.5",
    "@babel/register": "^7.4.4",
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "mocha": "^6.1.4",
    "nodemon": "^1.19.0",
    "reify": "^0.19.1",
    "request": "^2.88.0"
  }
}
```

client/package.json

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.0.1",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-github-login": "^1.0.3",
    "react-google-login": "^5.0.4",
    "react-images-upload": "^1.2.6",
    "react-redux": "^7.0.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.0.1",
    "react-social-login-buttons": "^2.3.1",
    "react-thunk": "^1.0.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "PORT=3001 react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "heroku-postbuild": "npm run build"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "enzyme": "^3.10.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.14.0",
    "enzyme-to-json": "^3.3.5",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
    "redux-mock-store": "^1.5.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "snapshotSerializers": [
      "enzyme-to-json/serializer"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: well you should define the full path. Where is main.js in the file structure? if its not inside `/client` then you need to tell it to look inside `/client/build` to get the build instead of static on the root

Comment: let me make an edit to show full folder structure

Comment: aka something like `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build')));` or put your build folder at the root and not in `/client`

Comment: i made an edit that shows the full folder structure.

Comment: randal, you aren't pointing at the right location. if you `console.log(path.join(__dirname, 'build'))` in `main.js` you would see its missing the `client` folder in the path :)

Comment: ok i will try that

Comment: Read my comments again :) i put in an example of what should fix it I think

Comment: `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build')));` points the client and build, so i guess ill use that. Im rewriting the code

Comment: im sorta confused, orginially my code was `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build')));` how did you assume  `console.log(path.join(__dirname, 'build'))` when the existing code was `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build')));` ?

Comment: im not assuming it. its in your code. you have 2 places where you call it. meaning you are actually doing this `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build')));` but before doing that you are also doing this `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));`

Comment: would be so kind enough to provide an answer. I'm confused at this point, in the meanwhile ill tinker with the code and see what happens. thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195304/discussion-between-john-ruddell-and-randal).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to expose the build folder in a few different places in the code.

You should drop `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));` as that path is invalid. Further down inside `main.js` you are doing the correct path, but your production if block is obsolete and can potentially mess up the paths again. So you can remove that as well.

Aka translate this

```
//build mode
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build')));
// if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build')));
  //
  app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendfile(path.join(__dirname = 'client/build/index.html'));
  })
// }
//build mode
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/client/public/index.html'));
})
```

to this

```
//build mode
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build')));
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/client/public/index.html'));
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation John :).